# TypeError: string indices must be integers when getting class fro span tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get `class` of `span` tag. The issue is that there are several `span` tag in a `div` of which i want class. Also each `span` has 2 Classes. 
Everytime i run the code i get the following error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

HTML is like this

```
<p class="card-list">
<span class="span1 class1"></span>
<span class="span2 class2"></span>
<span class="span3 class3"></span>
<span class="span4 class4"></span>
</p>
```

My code is

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
services = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'card-class'})

for eachitem in services:
    for contactspan in eachitem.find('p', {'class':'card-info'}):
        for element in contactspan:
            print(element["class"])
```

Error on following line

```
print(element["class"])
```

I am unable to figureout what is the issue with this.

Comment: could you please add a little more detail? how are you initializing your span, how are you parsing the dom?

Comment: add print(element) first to see what it is. the error says it is some string

Comment: I have updated the code in question.

Comment: print(element) will list all the <span class="span1 class1"></span> in that <p> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need a little more stuff like the source HTML to give a more thorough answer, but suffice to say you are trying to invoke indexing with a class name on a parsed string that can only accept integer indices.

How about this?
*The in and Out are from ipython terminal, please disregard those*

```
In [24]: html_doc = "<p class=\"card-list\"> <span class=\"span1 class1\"></span><span class=\"span2 class2\"></span><span class=\"span3 class3\"></span><span c
    ...: lass=\"span4 class4\"></span></p>"                                                                                                                     

In [25]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                          

In [26]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser') 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                                                                        

In [27]: for para in soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'card-list'}): 
    ...:     for span in para.find_all('span'): 
    ...:         print(span.get('class')) 
    ...:  
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                                                                                                        
['span1', 'class1']
['span2', 'class2']
['span3', 'class3']
['span4', 'class4']
```

Comment: Already tried that. It give error saying AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: It worked with some modification but in the list there is `None` added at the end, can you tell why and how can I remove that?

Comment: I'm not sure, you might have a span that has no class in your paragraph, why don;t you just remove it by removing the last element?